# How to run laravel server without port

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, server, virtualhost

When I run command `php artisan serve` It start working with `localhost:8000`

How can start it as `localhost.com`

Please help and guide me.

Comment: IP sockets always require a port. The IP address is just the "street", while the port is the "housenumber"

Comment: so, It is not possible as I want?

Comment: you can use a vhost for this... so don't use the artisan serve command, use apache or nginx and add a vhost in your webserver settings. And add an entry in your hosts file

Comment: agree to what goldlife says. you can do that. but if it is only for your development then I don't see any need of doing this.

Comment: No, you CAN'T run a socket without a port... but you CAN use an address without having to add ":8000" . It is not the same!

Answer (score 2):

`php artisan serve --port=80`

Then access it at http://localhost

when your you type no port in your browser the `http://` default is 80 so no need to type it.

Comment: This was assuming you are using Laravel 5.

Comment: I tried this but getting this error `[Fri Jul 29 17:35:03 2016] Failed to listen on localhost:80 (reason: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden
 by its access permissions.
)
`

Comment: Have you got something else bound to port 80 also what OS are you using?

Comment: `Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:80 (reason: Address already in use)`

Answer (score 0):

if you are on a mac you can install laravel valet

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/valet

cd into the directory where you keep your projects and run `valet park`

then whatever the folder name is you can just browse to `folder.dev` and it will run

Comment: I am using windows

Answer (score 0):

If you are running apache create virtual host and you won't need to run `php artisan serve` anymore

here is the steps

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/exampledomain.dev.conf
```

add following lines

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@exampledomain.dev
    ServerName exampledomain.dev
    #ServerAlias www.exampledomain.dev
    DocumentRoot /home/websites/exampledomain.dev/public

<Directory /home/websites/exampledomain.dev/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

then modify etc/hosts

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

add next line and save

```
127.0.0.1 exampledomain.dev
```

enable the site

```
sudo a2ensite exampledomain.dev.conf
```

and restart server

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

After that you can view the local site using this URL: `exampledomain.dev`

Comment: Just one notice here, `.dev` tld is now just like `.com` is - generic, so browsers now will try to resolve it ignoring your `hosts` file records. TLDR; don't use `.dev` tld for testing.

Answer (score -1):

Using Windows Explorer, go to **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc**

```
127.0.0.1:8000 localhost.com
```

Save it and copy it back to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc (You need administrator access to complete this job)

But this is not recommend way

Comment: can anybody explain why this not a good way ?